# Why is Magento deleting code automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, magento, e-commerce

I am creating a dropdown menu for links to categories in my Magento store using something I found here:

```
<select name="forma" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="Home">Home</option>
 <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
 <option value="Sitemap">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Everytime I save the static block the `ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"` gets deleted from the block automatically and obviously the dropdown's links do not work at all.

Does anyone know why this is? I am very confused.

Thanks

Comment: The Magento WYSIWIG editor has a blacklist somewhere in the XML that prevents the insertion of certain values. Are you in a shared hosting environment or do you have access to the codebase?

Comment: Yes I have access to everything - how do I disable some of the values or the blacklist?

Comment: You'll have to search through the XML configuration files in app - I know there are a lot of them, but I think in the CMS one is where you'll find the blacklist.